# Checking version of byobu, got `WARNING: ulimit -u is too low`. What does this mean?

Tags: ulimit, byobu

Like the question says, this is what I typed in

`$ byobu --version
byobu version 5.119
WARNING: ulimit -u is too low
tmux 2.5`

I'm not sure what this means.